# Swift CoreData passing selected row value between UITableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, segue

I'm new to Swift and coding, only about a month in and I am trying to build some simple UItableViews to set up some CoreData attributes.

The structure of my CoreData entities is a many-to-many relationship between the Workouts Entity and the Exercises Entity. (I would post some images but I don't have a high enough rep!)

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple settings menu where users can create a Workout and then create a series of Exercises within that Workout by using tableViews with a navigationController at the top (just like the iOS settings menu)

Currently I've got it working so that you can add some Workouts and then you can go to the Excercises tableView to add some Exercises. However I haven't been able to do two things:

1) How can I ensure that when a user adds an Exercise that it is assigned to the correct Workout that they've selected from the previous tableView?

2) How can I ensure that the Exercise tableView only shows Exercises of the Workout that they've selected?

I've done a lot of reading around the subject and think the answer is something to do with the segue from Workouts to Exercises (to pass the workoutName to the Exercises tableView by using a delegate? And then using NSPredicate to limit the Exercises shown to the Workout selected?

I'm not 100% sure, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code for the segue from Workouts to Exercises:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "excerciseMaster" {
        let ExcerciseMasterTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let workout = workouts[indexPath.row]
        let destinationTitle = workout.workoutName
        ExcerciseMasterTableViewController.title = destinationTitle
    }
}
```

Here's the code for my Exercises tableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExcerciseMasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// Create an empty array of Excercises
var excercises = [Excercises]()

// Retreive the managedObjectContext from AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use optional binding to confirm the managedObjectContext
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
    }

    fetchExcercises()
}

func fetchExcercises() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Excercises")

    // Create a sort descriptor object that sorts on the "excerciseName"
    // property of the Core Data object
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "excerciseName", ascending: true)

    // Set the list of sort descriptors in the fetch request,
    // so it includes the sort descriptor
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Excercises] {
        excercises = fetchResults
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // How many rows are there in this section?
    // There's only 1 section, and it has a number of rows
    // equal to the number of excercises, so return the count
    return excercises.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Excercise Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Get the Excercises for this index
    let excercise = excercises[indexPath.row]

    // Set the title of the cell to be the title of the excercise
    cell.textLabel!.text = excercise.excerciseName
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(excercise.sets)x\(excercise.reps)"
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(editingStyle == .Delete ) {
        // Find the Excercise object the user is trying to delete
        let excerciseToDelete = excercises[indexPath.row]

        // Delete it from the managedObjectContext
        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(excerciseToDelete)

        // Refresh the table view to indicate that it's deleted
        self.fetchExcercises()

        // Tell the table view to animate out that row
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        save()
    }
}

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let excercise = excercises[indexPath.row]
}

let addExcerciseAlertViewTag = 0
let addExcerciseTextAlertViewTag = 1


@IBAction func addExcerciseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var namePrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Add Excercise",
        message: "Enter Name",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var excerciseNameTextField: UITextField?
    namePrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField) -> Void in
        excerciseNameTextField = textField
        textField.placeholder = "Title"
    }

    namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",
        style: .Default,
        handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if let textField = excerciseNameTextField {
                self.saveNewItem(textField.text, workoutName: "Workout A")
            }
    }))

    self.presentViewController(namePrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func saveNewItem(excerciseName : String, workoutName: String) {
    // Create the new excercise item
    var newExcercise = Excercises.createExcerciseInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!, name: excerciseName)
    println(excerciseName)
    println(workoutName)

    // Update the array containing the table view row data
    self.fetchExcercises()

    // Animate in the new row
    // Use Swift's find() function to figure out the index of the newExcercise
    // after it's been added and sorted in our Excercises array
    if let newExcerciseIndex = find(excercises, newExcercise) {
        // Create an NSIndexPath from the newExcerciseIndex
        let newExcerciseIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newExcerciseIndex, inSection: 0)
        // Animate in the insertion of this row
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([ newExcerciseIndexPath ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        save()
    }
}

func save() {
    var error : NSError?
    if(managedObjectContext!.save(&error) ) {
        println(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "excerciseSettings" {
        let ExcerciseSettingsDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let excercise = excercises[indexPath.row]
        let destinationTitle = excercise.excerciseName
        ExcerciseSettingsDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.The segue is close. Your ExcerciseMasterTableViewController doesn't have a property named workout. You need to add

```
var workout:Workout!
```

to your ExcerciseMasterTableViewController.

Your seque should look more like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
if segue.identifier == "excerciseMaster" {
    let desitnationController = segue.destinationViewController as ExcerciseMasterTableViewController
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    let workout = workouts[indexPath.row]
    destinationController.workout = workout
    let destinationTitle = workout.workoutName
    desitnationController.title = destinationTitle // Usually you would put this in the viewDidLoad method of the destinationController
}
```

}

Then in your when you add exercises in your ExcerciseMasterTableViewController simply set their workout property

```
workout.exercises = exercises // See note in #2
```

2. To make sure only the correct exercises are shown, in your viewDidLoad set your exercises array to workout.exercises. Note that workout.exercises should be an NSSet, so you either need to convert your set to an array, or have exercises be of type NSSet instead of an array.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. Looks like the segue is good but I can't get the workout.exercises = exercises to work. I've added it to my saveNewItem function just below where I create the new exercise but Xcode throws up an error saying Workouts does not have a member named exercises. Could this be because it is not recognising the relationship between the Workouts entity and the Exercises entity? I have Exercises set up to have Workouts as a parent, so it should work?

Comment: I'm also unsure of the coding required to set the exercises array to workout.exercises - would I alter the original exercises variable I declare? Thank you

Comment: The relationship might exist in your data model, but have you updated your Workout class to have an exercises property (and vice versa)? Where you're new to this, the easiest way to do this would be to delete your managed object class files and have Xcode make new ones. To do this click on your xcdatamodeld, and click Editor>Create NSManagedObject Subclasses, then check off the ones you want

Comment: As you'll see in the new NSManagedObject subclasses, the exercises property of Workout is an NSSet. Therefor your exercises property you assign to workout.exercises must be an NSSet. Sets aren't great for displaying data, so I would suggest keeping your exercises property as an array, but when you are ready to save it, create a temporary NSSet (there is a setFromArray initializer).

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed it's a many-many relationship. When you generate your new NSManagedObject subclasses you'll see there are two methods for adding and removing objects to/from the many-many relationship.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me with this. I've set up the relationship as many-to-many but I'm struggling to convert between the workout array and the NSSet required and to set the workoutName when I add the exercise. I've also gone for a predicate to limit the exercises you see based on the workout that you select as I couldn't work out setting the exercises array to workout.exercises. Can this work in the same way?

Comment: That will work just fine. To add exercises to workouts and vice-versa just use the auto generated methods for adding and removing objects. The previous advice (creating an NSSet) was for a one-many relationship.

Comment: Thank you  - think I've got the exercise being added to Workouts now. Just need to fix the predicate, which I can't get working. Am using this at the moment:  let workoutPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Exercises.workouts CONTAINS %@", "\(workout.workoutName)") but it keeps generating an uncaught exception - any ideas?

Comment: Assuming workoutName is a string should be just workout.workoutName

Comment: Yes, workout.workoutName is coming through perfectly from the segue and I can use String interpolation to pass it in to the predicate as a string. The problem I'm now having is it won't compile with exercises.workout, I get the error Exercises.type does not have a member named 'workout'. I'm guessing this is because it's an array?

Comment: You seem to be conflating classes with objects. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep#Object

Comment: I'm really sorry - I've read through that article and I can't workout how to solve my problem. I've only been learning Swift for a month, so I think I've obviously bitten off more than I can chew by trying to work out all this CoreData stuff! I think I'll have to abandon this project and start with something simpler. Thanks for all your time and help though.

Comment: I'd recommend you find some literature on Object Oriented Programming. I believe some of the old Objective-C books/tutorials are quite good, there are some concepts you seem to be missing. Also review Apple's MVC (Model-View-Controller) guide. When you're done with that and have the basics, Stanford's iOS dev course was just updated in Swift. You can find it on iTunes U

Comment: Great suggestions, I'll have a look into it. Thanks for all your help